# asp.net mvc api json formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a query that returns something like this:

- OBJECT | QTY | ......
- Random_Name_1 | 5 | .....
- Random_Name_2 | 3 | ......

I want to return a  j-son like this

```
{"Success": true, "Message": "Total rows 8", "Data": { "Random_Name_1": {"QTY": 5 ... }, "Random_Name_2": {"QTY": 3 ... } } }
```

How can i accomplish this in a web API made on ASP.NET MVC4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i solved it, on monday I'll probably change it to be reflective..

```
               var x = tw.spCall(type).ToList();

                if (x.Count() == 0)
                    return new { Success = false, Message = "No data!" };

                DataSet temp = new DataSet();

                foreach (var y in x) {
                    if (temp.Tables[y.EQUIPMENT] == null) {

                        temp.Tables.Add(y.EQUIPMENT);
                        temp.Tables[y.EQUIPMENT].Columns.Add("id_key");
                        temp.Tables[y.EQUIPMENT].Columns.Add("PartNumber");
                        ...
                    };

                    DataRow row = temp.Tables[y.EQUIPMENT].Rows.Add();

                    row.SetField("id_key",y.id_key);
                    row.SetField("PartNumber",y.PartNumber);
                    ...

                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temp, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
// your data
var q = new[]
{
    new {OBJECT = "Random_Name_1", QTY = 5, TYPE = "A"},
    new {OBJECT = "Random_Name_2", QTY = 3, TYPE = "B"},
    new {OBJECT = "Random_Name_3", QTY = 8, TYPE = "B"}
};

// construct the object
var obj = new
{
    Success = true,
    Message = string.Format("Total rows {0}", q.Count()),
    Data = q.ToDictionary(
        item => item.OBJECT,
        item => item.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.Name != "OBJECT")
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(item, null)))
};

// serialize the object (note that you don't need to do that from web api)
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Note taht if you already know the structure of data (i.e. the columns) then you can make it more efficient by avoiding reflection. Means:

```
var obj = new
{
    Success = true,
    Message = string.Format("Total rows {0}", q.Count()),
    Data = q.ToDictionary(
        item => item.OBJECT,
        item => new { item.QTY, item.TYPE })
};
```

Comment: ohh ok I see what you're doing there, yeah i tried it, the problem is that, Random_Name_1 may be more than once, so with Random_Name_1, Random_Name_2, Random_Name_3 i would have 3 different tables, with the same data structure, bue "Random_Name" is the name of a machine, and is has the table of events (star/off/begin work/end work/ etc etc..

Comment: Then your data set cant be represented in the form you described. Check what JSON is. Each field in object MUST be unique. You can't have multiple fields with the same name in one JSON object. Use array instead of dictionary.

Comment: The thing is that I wanted to make only 1 call to the db, to retrieve lets say 50 tables(One for each machine i wanted to analyze), i wanted to create 1 js array for each table. So, i just put an identifier for each table in my query and then in C# I separated the tables without returning the identifier